# connect android to mysql database

Tags: java, android, database, connection, database-connection

I dont understand why my app crash....

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;    
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.os.StrictMode;    
import android.util.Log;    
import android.view.Menu;    
import android.view.MenuItem;    
import android.view.View;    
import android.widget.*;    
import java.sql.*;    
import java.util.*;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    EditText e;    
    Button bt;    
    ListView lv;    
    Connection connect;    
    SimpleAdapter sm;

    public void declere() {    
        e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_buscar);    
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_buscar);    
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_output);    
    }

    public void initilize() {    
        declere();    
        e.setText("SELECT * FROM TipoLugar");    
        connect = CONN("root", "teste", "teste_DB", "192.168.5.154:3306");    
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")    
    private Connection CONN(String user, String pass, String db, String server) {    
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new     
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();    
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);    
        Connection conn = null;    
        String connUrl = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

            connUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + ";" + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + pass + ";";

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connUrl);    

        } catch (SQLException se) {
             Log.e("ERROR", se.getMessage());    
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cl) {    
            Log.e("ERROR", cl.getMessage());    
        } catch (Exception e) {    
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }

        return conn;    
    }    

    public void querySQL(String COMMANDSQL) {    
        ResultSet rs;

        try {
            Statement statement = connect.createStatement();    
            rs = statement.executeQuery(COMMANDSQL);    
            List<Map<String, String>> data = null;    
            data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

            while (rs.next()) {    
                Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                datanum.put("a", rs.getString("code"));    
                datanum.put("b", rs.getString("descricao"));    
                data.add(datanum);
            }

            String[] from = {"a", "b"};    
            int[] to = {R.id.txt_titulo, R.id.txt_conteudo};    
            sm = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.modelo, from, to);    
            lv.setAdapter(sm);    
        } catch (Exception e) {    
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }    
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {    
        super.onCreate(b);    
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);    
        initilize();

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              querySQL(e.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

the error in log cat is this (Do you have any ideia what's this? :) )

```
07-08 16:51:29.200      632-632/app2.francisco.app2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
        at app2.francisco.app2.MyActivity.querySQL(MyActivity.java:88)
        at app2.francisco.app2.MyActivity$1.onClick(MyActivity.java:103)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

07-08 16:51:31.420      632-632/app2.francisco.app2 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 632 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `e.getMessage()` is `null` within the `catch` block of the `querySQL` method, so `Log.e` is passing `null` to `println`, which is throwing the `NullPointerException`.

Why the exception message is `null`, I can't say, but you can fix this by checking for `null` and providing a default value when it is:

```
public void querySQL(String COMMANDSQL) {
    ...
    try {
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String errorMessage = (e.getMessage() != null) ? e.getMessage() : "Unknown error";
        Log.e("ERROR", errorMessage);
   }
}
```

Comment: This show me an error.

String errorMessage = (e.getMessage() != null) e.getMessage() : "Unknown error";

Comment: @user3816937 Sorry.. typo on my part, left out the most important part of the ternary operator. Fixed now.

Comment: it falls on that error... and on the SQLEXCEPTION... Do u know why?

thx @LimbSoup

Comment: @user3816937 That sounds like another question, as your `NullPointerException` should be fixed. It would be impossible to root out the cause of an `SqlException` without knowing what the query was, the schema.. etc.

Comment: LimbSoup thx it was my mistake..... the query was wrong and the user too.................... sorry but thx for all

Answer (score 0):

it seems as though rs is null, which means the portion where you set it is not working
statement.executeQuery(COMMANDSQL); is null, so you need to follow the logic from that and find out what is causing it to be equal to null, it could be your sql syntax since you are setting it equal to text field input, also executeQUery and execute are different things, and return different values, I suggest looking at the API to make sure you are getting what you want http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Statement.html